# Why is there blank space to the right of my website?

Tags: html, css

I have been making my own personal site with Animate.css and noticed there was a blank spot to the right and couldn't figure out why

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>

    .hudson {
          color: white;
          position: relative;
          font-size: 60px;
          left: 400px;
          top: 110px;
          font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
            }

      .threeD {
        text-shadow: 
           0 1px 0 #ccc,
           0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
           0 3px 0 #bbb,
           0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
           0 5px 0 #aaa,
           0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
           0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
           0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
           0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
           0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
           0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
           0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
              }

      .p1 {
         position: relative;
         top: 75px;
         left: 100px;
         -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;

      }

      .p2 {
         position: relative;
         top: 85px;
         left: 100px;
         -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
      }

      .p3{
          position: relative;
          top: 95px;
          left: 95px;
          -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
      }

      .coding {
          position: relative;
          top: -325px;
          left: 535px;

      }

      .paracolor {
            color: skyblue;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
            }

      .img1 {
          position: relative;
          top: 250px;
          left: 20;
            }

    body {
    background-image: url(PICTURES1/mountains4.jpeg);
    background-size: 102%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
         }

  </style>
</head>
  <link rel=stylesheet href="CSS3/animate(1).css">
<body>
    <h2 class="hudson threeD animated fadeInDown">Hudson Reamer</h2>
    <p class="paracolor p1 animated fadeInRightBig">I am a young technology and coding enthusiast. I am currently studying HTML,CSS, and C++.</p>
    <p class="paracolor p2 animated fadeInLeftBig">I hope to one day go to MIT or Stanford  to study computor science of computor engineering.</p> 
    <p class="paracolor p3 animated fadeInRightBig">I will build people custom computors for an 100 dollar building fee and the price of the PC parts</p>
  <img class="coding animated fadeInDown" src="PICTURES1/coding.png" style="width:150px;height:150px;">
</body>
```

Thank you for the help and responses!

Comment: Could you indicate the white spot with screenshot?

Comment: How wide is that `mountains4.jpeg` file? As wide as your screen or less?

Comment: The picture is 1920x1080

Comment: You've got some grammatical/spelling errors in the text of the site.  See below for suggested text: Hudson Reamer    I am a young technology and coding enthusiast. I am currently studying HTML, CSS, and C++. I hope someday to attend MIT or Stanford to study either computer science or computer engineering.  I will build people custom computers for the cost of the parts plus a $100 assembly fee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The large area of whitespace on the right of your page is caused by *relative positioning*.

You are applying `position: relative` to all your elements. Then you're shifting all of them to the right with `left: 400px` and `left: 535px` and `left: 100px`, etc. The `left` property defines how far to push the element from the left edge.

Also, when an element is relatively positioned, its original space is reserved. So while the elements are shifting rightward, they are also keeping their original spaces (even though they're not there anymore), and the document is being lengthened horizontally.

Remove all the `left` properties and see the difference. Everything shifts left and the horizontal scrollbar disappears. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/dtjedkax/)

I'm not sure what your layout objective is but, simply for contrast, here's an alternative to consider: Instead of `relative` try `absolute` positioning, which removes the elements from the document flow, so their original space is eliminated.

Here's a good reference from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 2):

All your paragraph tags have are positioned left with 'x' amount of pixels

example

`p1`  from left position is 100px

`p2`  from left position is 100px

`p3`  from left position is 95px

Take the above out of your css and everything should be fine

**snippet below**

```html
  <style>

    .hudson {
          color: white;
          position: relative;
          font-size: 60px;
          left: 400px;
          top: 110px;
          font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
            }

      .threeD {
        text-shadow: 
           0 1px 0 #ccc,
           0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
           0 3px 0 #bbb,
           0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
           0 5px 0 #aaa,
           0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
           0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
           0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
           0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
           0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
           0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
           0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
              }

      .p1 {
         position: relative;
         top: 75px;
 
         -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;

      }

      .p2 {
         position: relative;
         top: 85px;
 
         -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
      }

      .p3{
          position: relative;
          top: 95px;
 
          -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
      }

      .coding {
          position: relative;
          top: -325px;
          left: 535px;

      }

      .paracolor {
            color: skyblue;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
            }

      .img1 {
          position: relative;
          top: 250px;
            }

    body {
    background-image: url(PICTURES1/mountains4.jpeg);
    background-size: 102%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
         }

  </style>
</head>
  <link rel=stylesheet href="CSS3/animate(1).css">
<body>
    <h2 class="hudson threeD animated fadeInDown">Hudson Reamer</h2>
    <p class="paracolor p1 animated fadeInRightBig">I am a young technology and coding enthusiast. I am currently studying HTML,CSS, and C++.</p>
    <p class="paracolor p2 animated fadeInLeftBig">I hope to one day go to MIT or Stanford  to study computor science of computor engineering.</p> 
    <p class="paracolor p3 animated fadeInRightBig">I will build people custom computors for an 100 dollar building fee and the price of the PC parts</p>
  <img class="coding animated fadeInDown" src="PICTURES1/coding.png" style="width:150px;height:150px;">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

its your hudson, p1, p2 ,p3 absolute left is making all the way to the right. you could replace "left:" in these styles with text-align: center;